# Operator norm and convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator with $X$ and $Y$ being vector spaces. Suppose that $\|T\| = A$.  Then is there a sequence $x_n$ with $\|x_n\|=1$ such that $\|Tx_n\| \to A$?

Conversely, if we know such a sequence exists, can we conclude that $\|T\|=A$?

To be honest, I'm completely clueless about this problem.  What sequence should I think of?  I only know that $A = \sup\limits_{x \in B(0,1) \subset X} \|Tx\|$, so $\|Tx\| \le A \|x\|$ for all $x \in X$.

Thank you.

Comment: Just use the definition of supremum. For each $n\in\Bbb N$, there is an admissible $x_n$ with $A\le \Vert Tx_n\Vert<A-1/n$.  It is not hard to find a counterexample for the second part (take a constant sequence).

Comment: "I only know that" yes, that's exactly what you have to use! The supremum is **the smallest** upper bound, not just an upper bound as you indicate with the word "so".

Comment: @David Mitra $A-1/n<\|Tx_n\|\le A.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks. Silly me...